# Convert DATETIME to varchar in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, datetime-format

I want to convert `DATETIME` to `VARCHAR` with `Friday 07-Feb-20 8:30 AM` this type of output. I tried to do it like this. But it didn't give the correct format that I want.

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE DATETIME,@SDATE VARCHAR(250)
SELECT @STARTDATE = SESSION_START  FROM SESSION_INFO WHERE SESSION_ID = 2071 //@STARTDATE = 2013-01-28 14:00:00.000
SET @SDATE = CONVERT(VARCHAR,@STARTDATE,100)
PRINT @GOOGLE  //Jan 28 2013  2:00PM
```

I want `day-mon-year hh:min AM/PM (Friday 07-Feb-20 8:30 AM)` this format. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [`format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for that e.g.

```
select format(current_timestamp, 'dddd dd-MMM-yy hh:mm tt');
```

Note: `format` doesn't perform as well as `convert` or `cast` but it has the added flexibility you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `format` as follows:

```
FORMAT (SESSION_START, 'dddd dd-MMM-yy hh:mm tt')
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b16f9342c453519427bdbb7eaf26a4fb) with the example output